# Exporting materials to seperate .tga UV map file in blender

Tags: animation, 3d, blender

Hi
I have added materials (colors) to a 3D model. How to export to an .obj file, along with a .tga file as a UV unwrapped file ? In other words, I want the .tga file to contain all materials (colors) that I added, so that an image file taken as reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First unwrap your model (UV textures & mapping) then bake the textures to an image file (render baking).

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:Manual/Render/Bake